# How to add table table-border in Div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here im using Bootstrap Div for creating User Page Here my two textbox(Name And Email) are touching each other please suggest me how can i write without touch each other and table-border table-hover in div

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>Enter YourName</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>Enter Email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>Enter Gender</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="radio" name="Gen" value="Male" ng-bind="Gender"/>Male
                <input type="radio" name="Gen" value="Female" ng-bind="Gender" />Fe-Male
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Hussain, Have you included the bootstrap file??

Comment: Here im using visualStudio2015

Comment: but its not solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a class to th the row you want to move, like this:

```
.row-spacing {
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z1pL7h2z/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default classes of Bootstrap. There's no need of making custom classes for spacing between two input boxes.

Check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rue8a4jp/

```
<div class="container-fluid">    
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Enter YourName</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Enter Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Email" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Enter Gender</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="Gen" value="Male" ng-bind="Gender" />Male</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="Gen" value="Female" ng-bind="Gender" />Fe-Male</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```